# What exactly IS in the weekly newsletter?

Tags: discussion, newsletter

I saw a mention of a newsletter a couple of times, and was wondering just what it is and what's the content?

Is it some original content?

Automated content culled from the site? (e.g. top voted/popular Qs and As for the week)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check them out here:

http://stackexchange.com/newsletters

Original content would be nice.